# For loop ENDFOR equivalent from PHP

Tags: c#, asp.net

In PHP I do the following to create a list. Note the lack of an "echo" statement.

```
<ul>
  <? for($x=1;$x<=10;$x++): ?>
    <li>This is line <?=$x?></li>
  <? endfor; ?>
</ul>
```

This is a very simple example, what I'm actually working with is a lot more complex. I'm trying to figure out how to accomplish the same thing in ASP.NET C#.

Basically, I want to start a loop, end the C# code, define a bunch of HTML which should be repeated, start a new C# snippit, end the loop. As per the example above in PHP, I'm looking for the .NET equivalent of for() and endfor; I'm trying to avoid outputting my code with C# logic.

If it is even possible!

What I'm NOT looking for is this:

```
<ul>
  <%
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
      Response.Write("<li>This is line " + i.ToString() + "</li>");
    }
  %>
</ul>
```

Is this possible with C#? Or am I possibly approaching this all wrong?

Comment: Are you just asking for `<% for (...) { %> <li>This is line <%: i.ToString() %> </li> <% } %>`? It might help to post what you're *actually* trying to accomplish rather than posting a sample that doesn't demonstrate what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: I appreciate what you're saying, but in this particular instance I can't post my code. It's pretty clear what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you after something like the more literal translation:

```html
<ul>
  <% for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) { %>
      <li>This is line <%= i %></li>
  <% } %>
</ul>
```

Comment: That works, thank you. I'll accept your answer when the wait timer lets me.